# PHP and Android Programmer, now working with freelance developers SVN? or what?

Tags: php, android, project-management, collaboration

I do some android work on my desktop and I am starting to do some PHP work on a website.  I just started doing some collaboration with some freelancers on both platforms.  I would also like to do more coding on my laptop (android and eclipse export and importing is annoying).  I have a GoDaddy shared hosting and a neglected Ubuntu 11.04 server at home.

I need to setup something to make this all easier, should I do some sort of SVN?  I don't make much money on my projects, so I don't want to pay for an online repository.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Dropbox" could be an alternative for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) would be your best bet which is free for private repos and uses [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 2):

A DVCS such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). Both can have online repositories set up on any server with shell access.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with free svn/git provided by [assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) and you can select free plan also from this link http://www.assembla.com/catalog/tag/Free?type=private

Answer (score 0):

You can try git free version needs to be open or google drive could be a.better option as its free, its desktop app could automatically sync your data online.